Exact form of the operator when its adjoint operator is given
I am studying the adjoint of an operator defined from a Banach space to another Banach space. Let $X$ and $Y$ be the Banach spaces. $X^*$ denotes the dual space of $X$. Let $T:X\to Y$ be a bounded linear operator. Suppose that $T^*:Y^*\to X^*$ be the adjoint of $T$. For arbitrarily chosen $x^*\in X^*$ there exists $\gamma\in Y^{**}$ such that
$$T^*(y^*)=\gamma(y^*)x^*.$$
Now, my question is what will be the exact form of $T$ (If we can compute)? Is this $T$ the adjoint of $T^*$?
My attempt: First we show that $T^*$ is well defined. For $y_1^*, y_2^*\in Y^*$ consider
$$
\begin{split} 
T^*(y_1^*)\neq T^*(y_2^*) & \implies \gamma(y_1^*)x^*\neq\gamma(y_2^*)x^*\\
& \implies \gamma(y_1^*)\neq\gamma(y_2^*)\\
& \implies y_1^*\neq y_2^*.
\end{split}
$$
Am I rightly proceeding?
Next, if the relation $T^*y^*(x)=y^*(Tx)$ holds true then plugging the value of $T^*y^*$ from above we get
$$\gamma(y^*)x^*(x)=y^*(Tx).$$
From here I could not able to compute the exact form of $T$. In which step I am doing wrong? Please help me. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.
$\textbf{After few discussions with julio_es_sui_glace the conclusion becomes:}$
From the answer posted by julio_es_sui_glace it is clear that

An operator $T^*:Y'\to X'$ will be an adjoint of some $T:X\to Y$ if and only if
$$T^{**}(J_X(x))=J_Y(T(x)).$$

One can also go through the discussion Is every operator adjoint for something?. In contrast of the above characterization it is not difficult to see that according to the given expression of the operator $T^*$ in the question, $T^*$ cannot be an adjoint operator. Indeed, for all $y^*\in Y^*$,
$$T^{**}(J_X(x))(y^*)=J_Y(T(x))(y^*)=y^*(Tx).\qquad \qquad (A)$$
Now, according to the given definition of the adjoint operator and given hypothesis in the question for any $x^{**}\in X''$ we have
$$
\begin{split} 
T^{**}(x^{**})(y^*) & =x^{**}(T^*y^*)\\
& =x^{**}(\gamma(y^*)x^*)\\
& =x^{**}(x^*)\gamma(y^*).\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad (B)
\end{split}
$$
Therefore, from $(A)$ and $(B)$ we have $y^*(Tx)=x^*(x)\gamma(y^*)$ which leads us to nowhere to compute $T$.

You have to look at $T^{}:X^{} \to Y^{**}$ to recover $T$ from $T^{*}$.

@geetha290krm can you please explain a little bit how I can proceed? Please

@julio_es_sui_glace Can you please elaborate my mistake? I am not able to understand.

Sorry it was my mistake for reading too fast

@julio_es_sui_glace it's ok no need to say sorry. Thank you very much for your concern.

What can you say about $T^{**}(\operatorname{ev}_x)(y^*)$?

$T^{}(\operatorname{ev}_x) \in Y^{}$

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You should prove that $T\subset T^{},$ i.e. $T^{}\mid_X=T.$


For simplicity, for a banach space $V$, $x \in V$, $y^* \in V’$ I will denote
$$y’(x) = \langle y’,x\rangle_V$$
Note that you are working here with topological duals $V’$ and not algebraic duals $V^*$.
$$V’ = \mathcal{L}_c(V,\mathbb{R}) \qquad V^* = \mathcal{L}(V,\mathbb{R})$$
This is an important matter to keep in mind since there is no algebraically reflexive infinite dimensional vector spaces, but they are plenty of topologically reflexive infinite dimensional Banachs (e.g. Hilbert spaces).

The definition of the adjoint in your case is the unique linear morphism $T^* : Y’ \to X’$ verifying:
$$\forall x \in X, \, y^* \in Y’, \quad \langle T^*(y^*),x\rangle_X = \langle y^*,T(x)\rangle_Y.$$

Its domain is $Y’$ since $T$ is bounded, and $T^*$ is also bounded.

Now if you know $T^*$ you can retrieve $T^*$ but not in an explicit way.
First notice that $T^{**}: X’’ \to Y’’$ is well defined and bounded, and recall that we have an isometry:
$$\begin{array}{rrcl}
J_X: & X & \to & X’’\\
& x & \mapsto & \operatorname{ev}_x: x^* \mapsto \langle x^* , x\rangle_X 
\end{array}$$
And it is thus injective.

Note that if you have a reflexive space $J_X$ is an homeo

Now how to get $T$? Let $x \in X, \, y^* \in Y’$
$$\langle T^{**} (\operatorname{ev}_{x}),y^*\rangle_{Y’} = \langle \operatorname{ev}_{x}, T^* (y^*) \rangle_{X’} = \langle T^*(y^*), x\rangle_X = \langle y^*, T(x) \rangle_Y = \langle \operatorname{ev}_{T(x)}, y^*\rangle_{Y’}. $$
So you can uniquely determine $T(x)$ since $J_Y$ is injective.

Now if you have a reflexive space, since we just proved that $T^{**}(\operatorname{ev}_{x}) = \operatorname{ev}_{T(x)} $ or more nicely $T^{**} \circ J_X = J_Y \circ T$, we get
$$J_Y^{-1} \circ T^{**} \circ J_X = J_Y^{-1} \circ J_Y \circ T = T.$$

Remark. The same reasoning works for algebraic duals $X^*$ and $Y^*$ if you remove the continuity and isometry considerations.

Thank you very much for the answer. First I shall try to understand it then definitely I will accept the answer. Thanks a lot.

After your given hints few hours before, I was convinced that $T^*$ will be an adjoint of $T$ if and only if $T^{**}(\operatorname{ev}x)=\operatorname{ev}{Tx}$. Am I wrong here?

No you are right, just check the las line of computations

But if I am right is the operator what I put there as $T^*$ that won't be an adjoint operator right? Another thing what do you mean by AoC?

I don’t get your question, could you reformulate it? AoC means Axiom of choice

Continuation from my previous comment where we agreed on the condition of an operator to be an adjoint one the operator $T^*$ what I put in the question that won't be an adjoint operator right? Another thing in your answer, what do you mean by the term AoC?

I’ve already answered for AoC. Yes your definition is odd, I don’t know how you got it, it seems false to me

Thank you very much for your cooperation and  answer.

Even assuming the axiom of choice, the canonical map $J_X:X\to X''$ need not have a continuous linear section (which, contrary to what you have written, would be a map $X''\to X$,) e.g., for $X=c_0$, the space of null sequences.

@Jochen yes I was confused with the algebraic case (which was the case for the first version of my answer). Thanks for the precision
